# What version of npm works with nodejs 0.10?

Tags: node.js, npm, apt-get, cartodb

I'm trying to install CartoDD as per instructions http://cartodb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

It requires nodejs 0.10 to work. This is what is specified in the instructions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cartodb/nodejs-010 && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs 
sudo apt-get install npm
```

It install nodejs 0.10 OK, but it gives this error message when trying to install npm:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: nodejs-dev
       Depends: node-request but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

There is an npm installation that I think was installed at the same time as nodejs:

```
~$ npm -v
1.4.3
```

Is this the right npm version for NodeJS 0.10? I'm not sure if it was there already. This apt-cache output is really more worrying since it says npm is not installed, but I have just executed it:

```
~$ apt-cache policy npm
npm:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.1.4~dfsg-1
  Version table:
     1.1.4~dfsg-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
```

There's something else that makes me think there is something wrong with this installation. `npm install` works for the most part, but later on in the installation, when trying to install the MAPS API, I get this errors:

```
Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'cairo' found
gyp: Call to './util/has_cairo_freetype.sh' returned exit status 0.
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:337:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/raquel/Windshaft-cartodb/node_modules/windshaft/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.26
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap/-/wordwrap-0.0.3.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/-/minimist-0.0.10.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/-/minimist-0.0.10.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap/-/wordwrap-0.0.3.tgz
npm http GET https://github.com/CartoDB/carto/archive/master.tar.gz
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/home/raquel/Windshaft-cartodb/node_modules/windshaft/node_modules/carto/node_modules/mapnik-reference'
npm ERR! error rolling back  windshaft@0.51.0 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/home/raquel/Windshaft-cartodb/node_modules/windshaft/node_modules/carto/node_modules/mapnik-reference']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/home/raquel/Windshaft-cartodb/node_modules/windshaft/node_modules/carto/node_modules/mapnik-reference' }
npm ERR! canvas@1.2.7-cdb1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.2.7-cdb1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/raquel/Windshaft-cartodb
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

I can get rid of that error if I do `sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-dev` and re-install with `npm install`, but I'm not sure if this is just a hack and I've done something wrong earlier by not installing the correct npm version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the complete list (between v0.10.0 - v0.10.40):

- node v0.10.0 -> npm v1.2.14
- node v0.10.1 -> npm v1.2.15
- node v0.10.2 -> npm v1.2.15
- node v0.10.3 -> npm v1.2.17
- node v0.10.4 -> npm v1.2.18
- node v0.10.5 -> npm v1.2.18
- node v0.10.6 -> npm v1.2.18
- node v0.10.7 -> npm v1.2.21
- node v0.10.8 -> npm v1.2.23
- node v0.10.9 -> npm v1.2.24
- node v0.10.10 -> npm v1.2.25
- node v0.10.11 -> npm v1.2.30
- node v0.10.12 -> npm v1.2.32
- node v0.10.13 -> npm v1.3.2
- node v0.10.14 -> npm v1.3.5
- node v0.10.15 -> npm v1.3.5
- node v0.10.16 -> npm v1.3.8
- node v0.10.17 -> npm v1.3.8
- node v0.10.18 -> npm v1.3.8
- node v0.10.19 -> npm v1.3.11
- node v0.10.20 -> npm v1.3.11
- node v0.10.21 -> npm v1.3.11
- node v0.10.22 -> npm v1.3.14
- node v0.10.23 -> npm v1.3.17
- node v0.10.24 -> npm v1.3.21
- node v0.10.25 -> npm v1.3.24
- node v0.10.26 -> npm v1.4.3
- node v0.10.27 -> npm v1.4.8
- node v0.10.28 -> npm v1.4.9
- node v0.10.29 -> npm v1.4.14
- node v0.10.30 -> npm v1.4.21
- node v0.10.31 -> npm v1.4.23
- node v0.10.32 -> npm v1.4.28
- node v0.10.33 -> npm v1.4.28
- node v0.10.34 -> npm v1.4.28
- node v0.10.35 -> npm v1.4.28
- node v0.10.36 -> npm v1.4.28
- node v0.10.37 -> npm v1.4.28
- node v0.10.38 -> npm v1.4.28
- node v0.10.39 -> npm v1.4.28
- node v0.10.40 -> npm v1.4.28

I recommend you to use [n](https://github.com/tj/n) or [nvwm](https://github.com/hakobera/nvmw) though. You don't have to worry about the versions with either of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I was also wondering... where did you get this list from?

Comment: Haha, I was expecting this. First, I went through the release notes but it took more time than I thought. So, I simply installed all node.js versions and checked their npm versions. And removed all node.js versions with `n rm 0.10.*` command.

Comment: @GökayGürcan do you know of any official source where we can this dependency map 2+ years later? Thanks. I ask because although `n` is a great tool for dev work, one would want to lock versions down to have less surprises and more reproducible builds when it come to continuous integration.

Comment: Here is a table which maps node releases to npm versions. https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/